# $.getJSON problem in spring mvc3.0

Tags: jquery

I have the following javascript function which i call on the submit button click....

function checkUser()
      {
          var uname=$('#username').val();
       var pword=$('#password').val();
       alert(uname);
       alert(pword);

```
      $.getJSON("login.html",{username: uname, password: pword},
              function(message){
   alert(message);
          });
  }
```

i am using spring mvc 3.0..... Following is the controller that i use...

package com.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class LoginController 
{
 @RequestMapping("/login.html")
 public @ResponseBody String getLoginStatus(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password)
 {
  System.out.println("\n\nin login controller\n\n");
  if(username=="apoorvabade" & password=="apoorva123")
  {
   return "Login successful!!!";
  }
  else
  {
   return "Login failed";
  }
 }
}

when i click on the submit button, the function corresponding to the /login.html action is not invoked.... i am using the DispatcherServlet to map the requests to the following....

here is the spring-servlet.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

/WEB-INF/jsp/
  
  
   .jsp

web.xml:

Spring Ajax Tutorial Project
 
  spring
  
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
       
  1

spring
  *.html

index.jsp

Can anybody tell me the problem please?

Comment: sorry charatcter limit had exceeded... so i will post my files individuaaly.... 

index.jsp: 

      function checkUser()
      {
          var uname=$('#username').val();
       var pword=$('#password').val();
       alert(uname);
       alert(pword);

       
       
          $.getJSON("login.hml",{username: uname, password: pword},
                  function(message){
       alert(message);
              });
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has to do with your submit function. You didn't show that. I ran your function on my page. `checkUser` is good to go.